# Deserialize dynamic Json to c# object using framework 2.0

Tags: c#, json, .net, deserialization, .net-2.0

In my project I am using .NET Framework 2.0. I want to deserialize dynamic JSON to a C# object but I don't want to use a predefined class for this. I want something like the `dynamic` keyword which is supported by .NET Framework 4.0. Is this possible with .NET Framework 2.0?

Answer (score 2):

You can not use `dynamic` but, since [Json.Net](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json)'s *JObject* implements `IDictionary` interface, it can be used as a dictionary.

```
var jObj = JObject.Parse("{a:1, b:{c:3} }");
int i = (int)jObj["b"]["c"];
```